# error with prepare() function

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this login page that I writes it while watching a tutorial on Udemy. His code works properly, but in my code (the same), I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

This is the code:

```
<?php
    //$var = 'This is our first web app page';
    //echo $var;

    //Connection Variables:
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "graphic_db";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "root";

    //Connection to SQL:
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Error messagin enabled:
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //Adding a character set:
    $conn = exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");

    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $sum = 0;
    $error_msg = "Please type a username and a password";
    if(isset($_POST['login_submit']))
    {
        //Start a session:
        session_start();
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if(empty($user) && empty($pass))
        {
            echo $error_msg;
            $pass = '';
        }
        if(empty($user) || empty($pass))
        {
            echo $error_msg;
            $user = '';
            $pass = '';
        }
        if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass))
        {
            //SQL:
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = :u AND password= :p LIMIT 1");
            $query->bindParam(":u", $user);
            $query->bindParam(":p", $pass);
            //Execute query:
            $query->execute();
            $number_rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            if($number_rows>0)
            {
                echo $user;
                $_SESSION = $user;
                $_SESSION = $pass;
                header("Location: /pages/home.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Invalid username or password";
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            //echo $user;
        }
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['login_submit']))
    {
        echo "Login button not clicked";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$conn = exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");` - what does that do and what does `function exec()` return?

Comment: $conn = exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4"); is to accpet arabic words inside MySQL. and exec() I dont know how to see what is returns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You destroy the *$conn* object with this statement:

```
$conn = exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
```

Replace it by:

```
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
```

Note that from PHP 5.3.6 onwards, you can set the character set in the connection string, like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname; charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

The separate `exec` call is then no longer necessary.